# Hide call logs across user profiles

Tags: multi-user, 7.1-nougat, call-history, profiles

I've created two user profiles on my android phone. One Main and the other one(let's call it Child) is a separate user(**NOT** the *default* Guest). But whenever I switch between users, the call logs can be seen which were made from the other profile, ie. calls made from the Main profile can be seen in the Child profile and vice-versa. I don't want to share my call logs across profiles. I searched for some viable switch or option to disable this in settings, but couldn't find any. Googling with the post's title along with android tag results in some log hiding apps which is not what I'm looking for! How can this be disabled natively from android options/settings itself? Or can it be done via some root 'tweak' if the rom is rooted as in my case.

Android OS - Nougat v7.1.2
Root Status - Rooted

Comment: Then the whole point of multi-user seems void to me. For eg, in windows users documents/pictures/videos/music are not shared across profiles. Unless a person fiddles around in Users folder and have necessary permissions to do so. So in my mind, I'm looking at multi-user as same as in windows. Apart from 3rd party apps, the default apps(messages/phone/gallery) should have separate space, IMHO

Comment: That seems to be the design- see source quoted in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access user profile and tap on `More Settings` (the second one in orange is child profile with *Bom* as name)

[image]

You will see yourself and child profile as below

[image]

Tap the cog icon on right and **disable**

`Turn on phone calls and SMS`

That's it.

If you **enable**, it gives you a warning that your calls and SMS would be shared as shown

[image]

Tested on stock 7.1.2

But the drawback is that child user can't use the phone or SMS

This is the [designed behaviour](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user)

> By default, only the primary user has full access to phone calls and texts. The secondary user may receive inbound calls but cannot send or receive texts. The primary user must enable these functions for others.
>
> Note: To enable or disable the phone and SMS functions for a secondary user, go to Settings > Users, select the user, and switch the Allow phone calls and SMS setting to off

While it is not explicitly mentioned that secondary user will see call logs of primary user and vice versa, once the primary user enables then everything is accessible to secondary user (remember **default** is not to allow , if you do, there is a price to be paid )